# "Clustered index" and "Order by Clause"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there any difference between **Clustered Index** and **Order by Clause**?

I have to populate the Dropdown from the Master Table and following is the query.

```
Select Id, Name from Table Order by Name
```

Should I use the **Order by Clause** Or **Clustered Index** for the above task?

**EDIT**

Below is the schema of the table

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[lookup]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lookup](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lookup_ID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[lookup]') AND name = N'IX_lookup_Name')
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_lookup_Name] ON [dbo].[lookup]
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a clustered index on `Name` as well. But right now it is not showing in the schema. Sorry, I don't know why.

Comment: I guess, you should order by whatever requirement is (Id or Name). Name looks like correct order field to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apples and Oranges. A clustered index is a storage option. An ORDER BY is a query option. If you need ordered results, the **only** way to get them is to add an ORDER BY clause to your query. Period.

An index *may* help the query optimizer generate a more efficient plan and leverage the index as a means to satisfy the ORDER BY requirement. But by no means will the presence of an index, clustered or non-clustered, guarantee any ordering of a result.

So you absolutely need ORDER BY in your queries. You also *may* consider an index by `Name` column to help this the query. Whether an index will be used or not, it depends on many more factors. you should read [Designing Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190804.aspx) and [The Tipping Point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, In case I am using clustered index on Name, It guarantees to show the Name in ascending order. You can test it also.

Comment: I can absolutely assure you you are wrong in your assumption.

Comment: Sorry, I tested this my end. It sort the records by Name in case we use the clustered index on Name

Comment: You should read this: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx. And the explanation.

Comment: SQL, Remus is right.  A clustered index does not guarantee a sort order; but it can increase performance when sorting.  A query without an ORDER BY returns unsorted results regardless of what you see in your testing.  http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/clustered-indexes-returning-incorrect-order.13251/

Comment: @RemusRusanu You have some bogus invisible characters in your sqlblog link, so it gives 404 if you click it, but the browser would remove the characters from display so you won't understand why it's 404 from here but works when found with google despite the URLs look identical.

Comment: I can't edit the comment, here is the link again: [http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A index allows for quick searching filtering "WHERE CLAUSE" but also has the added bonus in that data will be sorted.

example

This is how data would be saved in the table.

```
ID    Name
1     Jack
2     Bob
3     Jill
```

If you add a clustered index on Name(ASC) this is how it will be saved (primary keys are always stored along with each indexed for look up infomation)

```
2     Bob
1     Jack
3     Jill
```

So using your SQL

```
Select Id, Name from Table Order by Name
```

For a select without the clustered index, the database will check to see if an index exists that can help do its work quicker. It will not find any so it will select the data from the table, sort it, and then return.

For select with the clustered index, the database will check to see if an index exists that can help do its work quicker. It will find the index on name that is sorted ASC. It can just select the ID and Name from the index, and then return as it knows that the data is sorted already.

So without the index on name the database has to sort the data every time the query is run.
With the index, the sort happens when data is Inserted or Updated (which slows updates a little bit) The difference is that it only needs to sort once and not every time.

Comment: Is there anything like, without using the order by and we have only clustered index to get the data sorted. System does not guarantee to sort it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. If you only have a clustered index and no order by, that would leave the primary key and clustered index. As the clustered index would give no benefit to the query I would assume that the scan on the table would be used and the clustered index be ignored which would result in a select that would not be ordered. I am not sure why you don't want the order by in the query but still want the results ordered. You may be able to force the query to use the clustered index but that is not the best way of going about things.

Answer (score 0):

If Id is your primary key(that is common scenario) and is used in joins, you should create clustered index on Id.
But for searching performance gain, you should create nonclustered index on Name which will include Id.

Comment: I am selecting both Id and Name without where clause

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index and an order by clause are two completely different things. A clustered index decides how the rows in the stored table are sorted. An order by clause decides how the results of the query should be ordered.

A nonclustered index creates another "shadow table" in the DB storage, which is ordered on the indexed columns. It also contains the primary key, so that it can quickly find the right row in the "real" table. A best practice for database design is to create a clustered index on the primary key (unless there are reasons against it). Any other columns that need to be indexed can be handled in nonclustered indexes.

To optimize performance it is much more important that the `where` clause conditions can use an index than that the order by can.

Answer (score 0):

***My first question*** is:  What is the business use case? If the answer is "display the rows in name order", then ORDER BY Name.

Since you mentioned that you already have a non-clustered index on Name anyway, you should be good to go.

I also imagine that you will be filtering data on 'Name' anyway, so you'll already be making use of the index.

***My second thought***:  Are you prematurely optimizing this?  Is the table going to have thousands or millions of rows?  If not, you probably won't notice whether or not an index exists anyway.  And if you do have thousands of rows, how well will the dropdown box behave without filtering?

**We can do a lot of guessing, so it is always best if you profile the queries in your environment.**

In general, you put a CLUSTERED INDEX on incrementing values (IDENTITY, creation dates, etc) or if the data is relatively static.  Not every table requires a clustered index.

Comment: For millions of records, does the clustered index provide a noticeable performance difference?