# Get a table of dates of last 14 days (2 weeks) starting from previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query which gives a coloumn of DATES of last 14 days
starting from yesterday.

Example:

```
Dates 

2012-06-21
2012-06-20
2012-06-19
--
-
```

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I tried this by retrieving from my previous table but it takes a lot of time  select  Distinct convert(nvarchar(10), TimeLog, 120) As Dates from LogData order by  convert(nvarchar(10), TimeLog, 120) DESC ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH n(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (14) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT Dates = DATEADD(DAY, -n, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) FROM n
ORDER BY n;
```

Comment: Cool answer, couldn't you get rid of the `ORDER BY [object_id]` in 1st query and `ORDER BY n` in second query though?

Comment: Applying `ROW_NUMBER()` alone does not necessarily mean you will get 1-14 as the result. You might observe that most of the time but it's not guaranteed. That `ORDER BY` is for the `TOP`, not for the result. The final `ORDER BY` could have also been `ORDER BY Dates DESC` - it has little to do with the number in the CTE.

Comment: (For example, change my second `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY NEWID()`.)

Comment: Interesting, of course this is offtopic, but is this because sys.objects is actually a view? if sys.objects was a table and [object_id] it's clustered index, we wouldn't need `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin you are being lulled into a myth. There is no order without order by, clustered index or not. Usually that's the way SQL Server will decide to return the data, but it is not guaranteed. If you want and expect a certain order, you MUST add an order by.

Comment: Thanks for explanation - this helped too http://stackoverflow.com/q/6196699/903056

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

```
;with days(day) as
(
    select getdate() - 1 as day
        union all
    select day - 1
        from days
        where day > dateadd(day, -14, getdate())
)
select cast(day as date) from days
```

Comment: Minor quibble, OP asked for the resultset to start with yesterday.

Comment: You should delimit keywords like `day` IMHO. Also compare the plans and STATISTICS TIME. You might be surprised that the query that actually touches objects has lower duration, fewer reads and accurate estimates.

Comment: Oooh... be careful, Alex.  That's a "Counting Recursive CTE" and they play hell with resources and performance even on small row counts. Please see the following article for how bad they really are.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/